# Angular/TypeScript: Right TypedJSON schema

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, typed

I'm not sure of the current implementation... How can I be sure, when I retrieve each property from my JSON database, that each of them is right typed/parsed/serialized with my exported FMTyped class?

I exported and declared FMTyped in the right component and service, but if I delete the content of **ectm-fanmissions.typed.ts**, I don't see any differences (http://localhost:4200/)...

Should I use interfaces, classes, constructors...? Should I export each of them (export XXX name {}) even If I only use the parent class FMTyped?

When I use a converter like **json2ts** (http://json2ts.com/), the converted schema is incorporated into a declared module called namespace:

```
declare module namespace {

    export interface Characteristics {
        custommotions: boolean;
        customcreatures: boolean;
        customobjects: boolean;
        customsounds: boolean;
        customtextures: boolean;
        customscripts: boolean;
        customgamesys: boolean;
        bgmusic: boolean;
        movies: boolean;
        map: boolean;
        automap: boolean;
        booksandscrolls: boolean;
        goaldescription: boolean;
    }

    export interface Details {
        author: string[];
        description: string;
        game: string;
        ttlg: string;
        category: string;
        contest: string;
        language: string[];
        version: number;
        newdark: boolean;
        newdarkminrequiredversion: number;
        firstmisreleasedate: number;
        lastmisupdatedate: number;
        characteristics: Characteristics;
    }

    export interface Download {
        main: string;
        mirror: string[];
    }

    export interface Walkthrough {
        url: string;
        language: string;
    }

    export interface Extras {
        download: Download[];
        screenshots: string[];
        youtube: string;
        walkthrough: Walkthrough[];
    }

    export interface RootObject {
        index: number;
        _id: string;
        name: string;
        details: Details;
        extras: Extras;
    }

}
```

is that ok? How can I use that in my component and the related service? What do I have to do with this? How can I include this piece of code? Any tutorial or something?

This is my JSON database: **ectm-fanmissions.json**

```
[
  {
    "index": 0,
    "_id": "58fc458815350f4c0e3454a2",
    "name": "cillum excepteur deserunt eiusmod",
    "details": {
      "author": [
        "Gregory Rhodes",
        "Jonathan Linat"
      ],
      "description": "Dolore labore aute incididunt Lorem excepteur enim sit mollit. Voluptate adipisicing incididunt non pariatur labore occaecat non ipsum labore. Voluptate irure labore proident non Lorem minim sint velit sint id elit. Adipisicing voluptate commodo reprehenderit anim fugiat laboris dolore sit enim elit labore nulla. Pariatur elit aute officia sint. Duis mollit pariatur sit consequat et fugiat.\n\nQuis adipisicing labore minim anim consectetur ea laborum laboris amet nulla. In qui labore velit quis cupidatat ipsum sit do ipsum eu ex elit laboris. Duis aute laboris in elit aliqua eiusmod excepteur culpa nisi.",
      "game": "TDP",
      "ttlg": "http://www.ttlg.com/forums/showthread.php?t=120288",
      "category": "Dock/Harbour/Port/Ship",
      "contest": "Thief Reloaded Contest",
      "language": [
        "polish",
        "dutch"
      ],
      "version": 1.3,
      "newdark": true,
      "newdarkminrequiredversion": 1.24,
      "firstmisreleasedate": 1094296286179,
      "lastmisupdatedate": 1492047084343,
      "characteristics": {
        "custommotions": true,
        "customcreatures": true,
        "customobjects": true,
        "customsounds": false,
        "customtextures": false,
        "customscripts": true,
        "customgamesys": true,
        "bgmusic": false,
        "movies": false,
        "map": true,
        "automap": true,
        "booksandscrolls": false,
        "goaldescription": false
      }
    },
    "extras": {
      "download": [
        {
          "main": "http://thiefmissions.com/m/chonmigoroshiv2",
          "mirror": [
            "http://95.31.27.16/fan-missions/thief2/breathing_corpses/T2FM-BreathingCorpses[MULTI][07April2017].zip",
            "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9b8asJ7aeC0blM5MXAtaHd4bjQ/view?usp=sharing"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "screenshots": [
        "http://darkfate.org/view/simple/files/fan-missions/thief2/breathing_corpses/screenshots/dump002.jpg",
        "http://darkfate.org/view/simple/files/fan-missions/thief2/breathing_corpses/screenshots/dump000.jpg",
        "http://darkfate.org/view/simple/files/fan-missions/thief2/breathing_corpses/screenshots/dump002.jpg"
      ],
      "youtube": "sTCA4RFvNCQ",
      "walkthrough": [
        {
          "url": "http://www.zinkchristine.de/la5e.html",
          "language": "spanish"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

This is my TypedJSON Schema: **ectm-fanmissions.typed.ts**

```
export class FMTyped {
  index: number;
  _id: number;
  name: string;
  details: Details;
  extras: Extras;
}

class Details {
  author: string[];
  description: string;
  game: string;
  ttlg: string;
  category: string;
  contest: string;
  language: string[];
  version: string;
  newdark: boolean;
  newdarkminrequiredversion: string;
  firstmisreleasedate: Date;
  lastmisupdatedate: Date;
  characteristics: Characteristics;
}

class Characteristics {
  custommotions: boolean;
  customcreatures: boolean;
  customobjects: boolean;
  customsounds: boolean;
  customtextures: boolean;
  customscripts: boolean;
  customgamesys: boolean;
  bgmusic: boolean;
  movies: boolean;
  map: boolean;
  automap: boolean;
  booksandscrolls: boolean;
  goaldescription: boolean;
}

class Extras {
  download: Download[];
  screenshots: string[];
  youtube: string;
  walkthrough: Walkthrough[];
}

class Download {
  main: string;
  mirror: string[];
}

class Walkthrough {
  url: string;
  language: string;
}
```

This is the service I use to retrieve my JSON database: **ectm.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { FMTyped } from './../apidata/ectm-fanmissions.typed';

@Injectable()
export class EctmService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  private apidataEctmFanmissionsUrl = './../apidata/ectm-fanmissions.json';

  getFMs(): Observable<FMTyped[]>{
    return this._http.get(this.apidataEctmFanmissionsUrl)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }

}
```

This one is the component where I need to show my JSON database properties: **ectm-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { FMTyped } from './../../apidata/ectm-fanmissions.typed';
import { EctmService } from './../ectm.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ectm-list',
  templateUrl: './ectm-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ectm-list.component.css']
})
export class EctmListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _ectmService: EctmService) { }

  fanmissions: FMTyped[];

  loadFMs() {
    this._ectmService.getFMs()
      .subscribe(fanmissions => this.fanmissions = fanmissions, err => { console.log(err); });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadFMs();
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there a problem somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure of the current implementation... How can I'd be sure that, when I retrieve each property from my JSON database, is right typed with my exported FMTyped class? What's the difference between 'class' and 'interface'? Could I declare a module ?

Comment: The way you have used the class (without constructor) is more like an interface (which I suggest you use). If you console log your data it doesn't say that your data is of type `FMTyped`, it's just a POJO :)

Comment: Read about classes and interfaces: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html